# Find the CI for a given interval of HDI?

Tags: confidence-interval, kernel-smoothing, highest-density-region

I'm working with big data that doesn't fit well to a distribution but often exhibits a peak (maybe two). I'm looking for a method to calculate the confidence for a given range around the mode.

For example, if my mode (value with highest KDE) is 50 and I establish an acceptable range of 10 around the mode, what is my confidence that I'll be in this range.

I've been successful with following the HDI methods within R from https://rdrr.io/cran/HDInterval/man/hdi.html to find the range based on a given CI, but I'm attempting to the reverse the process.

My brute-force method would consider something like calculating the difference between the upper/lower values across different CI input until I find a the maximum confidence for a given delta between upper and lower.

Another thought was to "count" all observations outside the given range as compared to the number of observations within the acceptable range of values... but I think that is more frequentist and breaks some rules on what CI represents.

I'm sure there's a better way?

The goal of this is to compare how the CI changes across different datasets (or time periods) following a constant range of acceptable values around the mode. Data is often multimodal and I'm trying to avoid constraints of fitting to a distribution.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the CI for a given range around the mode," what it means to "establish an acceptable range," and what an "equivalent CI" might be?  These phrases suggest you might not be using the term "CI" in a conventional way, so it would help to have a clear definition of what you mean by it.  You also refer to a "mode," presumably of some hypothesized data-generating distribution. Could you tell us what you assume about that distribution?  Would it be any unimodal distribution?

Comment: I made some edits in an attempt to clarify.  Admit that might background is not stats.  I want to understand how "confident" we can be that an observation will be within a given range around the mode.  There is no formal distribution, I used KDE as a data-driven approach to finding mode.  Methods of HDI show promise, but I'd rather input range and see confidence (not other way around).  Another clarification is that my data represents the entire population (N=n), but there's potential of a few pieces of missing data (quality or collection issues, 0-10% missing).